# While writing/editing an answer, can cursor be redirected to edit screen if I click on markdown?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown-rendering

Often, I find my self clicking on the markdown section of an answer that I wan't to edit and then realize that I need to scroll up and change text in the edit screen.

Can a new feature **automatically take the cursor to the corresponding location in the edit screen** if I click on the markdown section?

I realize this might not be worth the effort that goes into writing the code but has anyone else ever been irked by this?

Answer (score 1):

I do this sometimes, so I know dem feels. I'm not sure your feature request is feasible though. I've never built anything like that, but I'd imagine it'd be quite tedious.

I would suggest you check out http://stackedit.io. It solves this exact problem and is packed full of other awesome features. I use it for when I am trying to put together a question for Stack Overflow. I also use it for creating/uploading gists to github.